# How to replace an unlimited amount of spaces in a string by only one space in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a string that can contain, between characters (other than spaces), one or more spaces.

I would like to replace an undetermined number of spaces by only one space.

Example:

```
3 root hadoop        332 2020-03-11 10:09
```

Becomes:

```
3 root hadoop 332 2020-03-11 10:09
```

or

```
3 root    hadoop   332 2020-03-11 10:09
```

becomes:

```
3 root hadoop 332 2020-03-11 10:09
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: I'd try `sed` .

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array:

```
$ x=(3 root hadoop        332 2020-03-11 10:09)
$ echo ${x[*]}
3 root hadoop 332 2020-03-11 10:09
```

Comment: would even work with variable